# OS X command as an Alias fails with the error '9:13: execution error: The variable Base is not defined. (-2753)'

Tags: bash, alias

I have a command I'm running in OS X.  It works perfectly:

`$ osascript -e 'quit app "Base"' && cd /Users/davechambers/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/ && ./adb pull data/data/uk.co.davechambers.pegboard/databases/we-need-db ~/Desktop/ | open -a "Base"`

I made it into an alias via:

`$ alias pullRoom="osascript -e 'quit app "Base"' && cd /Users/davechambers/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/ && ./adb pull data/data/uk.co.davechambers.pegboard/databases/we-need-db ~/Desktop/ | open -a "Base""`

When I run `pullRoom` however I get the error:

`9:13: execution error: The variable Base is not defined. (-2753)`

How should I have defined the alias so `pullRoom` will work?

Comment: Have a second look at where the quoting `"` for the alias begins and where it ends.

Comment: @muru Thanks for the tip. I'll check later when I'm back at my machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stuff like this can quickly get you into quoting hell :-) I usually go with a shell function in such situations.

```
function pullRoom() {
    osascript -e 'quit app "Base"' &&
       cd /Users/davechambers/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/ &&
       ./adb pull data/data/uk.co.davechambers.pegboard/databases/we-need-db ~/Desktop/ |
    open -a "Base"
}
```